# Where to store and mantain production code making it available for users to include its url

Tags: php, jquery, store

Let's say we created a small widget or web app. or just a plugin - and we want to distribute it to the public. (JS, jQuery...)
...and we have no server- or we are afraid it will close one day.
...and we'd like to provide that script  like an url-to-script to be included into a script tag.
Like we do with the jQ library -- Is there any provider that allows us to store codes and generates a livetime url to it?? That we can mantain, change or fix it anytime without the need to inform all users? 
Have Google something like that?
Or am I dreaming?

Comment: Have you not just described a CDN?

Comment: Heheh, have I? And that is...?

Comment: @roXon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: @roxon Sorry, It's basically just a server where your files reside. The files can then be called in a request via a url. Though I think it'd be overkill for what you want. The answer by diEcho sounds more reasonable. Here is some info on CDNs though just in case you're interested. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload on **[github](https://github.com/)**. It's free for open-source projects, and you can even link directly to the repo's master branch; example:

`https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json_parse.js`

(There are good reasons not to do that as a general rule — the master branch could get a breaking change committed to it, for example — but it's there if you need it.)

Comment: would each user not have to fetch from his git repo for any new upgrades though?

Comment: It's even free if the project is open-source.

Comment: @martswite: You can link to trunk. Example: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json_parse.js

Comment: @martswite: Mind you, there are good reasons to grab your own copy rather than doing that (you don't want your site breaking because they've committed a breaking change to the tip). But still, it's there if one wants it.

Comment: @T.J Crowder , i was also not aware of such usability ; Thanks for sharing, i m gonna update my answer with your help; Thanks

Comment: Yes, I ment something that allow users to be 'hands Free' and allowing us to mantain that code.

Comment: @roXon what means by `secure way` ? if u want to distribute your code then github is best. btw i dont rely on google

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Very good point there with regards to pulling your own copy

Comment: @diEcho: Hope you don't mind, I consolidated some comments into the answer. (Appreciated the shout-out, btw, but couldn't quite make myself leave it in when I did the edit...)

Comment: @TJ it's my pleasure :) You the THE GURU ...no problem